# Vague Image Recognition in Python

Tags: python, image-processing

So my goal here is to take an image input and get out a list of the shapes contained in it as an output. Of course, the shapes will not be anything like 'triangle' or 'square', but just lists of contiguous pixels of like values. 
My first attempt used a recursive algorithm which 'roamed' the image through paths of like-colored pixels, and added all the ones it could get to to the shape list. This worked for small images, but quickly exceeded the max. recursion depth for larger images.

My current attempt is Iterative, but doesn't want to work. 
http://pastebin.com/seLbnGE4

Are there any better ways to do it, or are there modules or methods which already exist which would fit my needs?

Comment: Looking over your pastebin code, actually, this seems like a problem: `UnHit = [CoordList[0]]`. Should the `0` be a `:`?

Answer (score 3):

what you're looking for sounds like "image segmentation" (cf [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_(image_processing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_%28image_processing%29) ). Usually a difficult math problem but implemented in OpenCV.

You may consider using level sets and the "Chan-Vese Algorithim" (cf http://www.univ-pau.fr/~cgout/viscosite/old/20032004/veseChanIJCV2002.pdf
ftp://ftp-sop.inria.fr/odyssee/Team/Rachid.Deriche/Lectures/MPRI/IEEEIP2001.pdf )

A convex optimization framework for segmentation into more than 2 regions is an open math problem of great interest.

Comment: there's something funky with your first link. The last end-paranthesis is not a part of the link, but when I edit, the preview is fine, without me doing anything?